# File movement monitoring and alerts

Tags: monitoring, files, alerts

We have applications that integrates to other applications through files exchanging.
We needed to be able to be notified on the following situations:

- Files are accumulating on a certain folder, reaching a defined number of accumulated files;
- A file is present on a folder without being taken by the app for more than a specified number of minutes;
- A folder has been empty with no file movement for more than a specified number of minutes;

Is there any tool for Windows that would allow me to set e-mail alerts upon those events? Preferrably a free one :)

I believe this might be a stupid question, but I swear I tried to google it for two days and I came up only to the wrong tools, or tools too difficult to learn.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Cheers,

Jonathas Carrijo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux you can use `inotify` and `dnotify` to monitor the folders and have a script that is doing what you need. Take a look on `incrond` too.

On Windows you could write a powershell script and use [FileSystemWatcher Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517460/is-there-anything-like-inotify-on-windows

Comment: Thanks, Mr Vutcovici. Actually, I fogot to say that our servers run on Windows.

Comment: The post you mentioned referenced a Java API http://jnotify.sourceforge.net which seems a promising choice for our needs.